# Parsing formatted C strings that are divided into parts

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, pointers, struct

I want to implement a function that decomposes a given string. but i'm not sure how to go about it. any help is appreciated.

```
/* Parses *str and creates a new StringBundle object containing the
 * separate fields of *str.
 *
 * Pre: str points to a GIS record string, properly terminated
 *
 * Returns: a pointer to a new proper StringBundle object
 */
 StringBundle* createStringBundle(const char* const str){

 }
```

for example this string separated by '|':

```
901051|Becker|Locale|NM|35|Eddy|015|322833N|1040812W|32.4759521|-104.1366141|||||959|3146|
Carlsbad East|11/01/1992|
```

I want to break it up into a collection of strings some of which may be empty.

```
0 901051
1 Becker
2 Locale
3 NM
4 35
5 Eddy
6 015
7 322833N
8 1040812W
9 32.4759521
10 -104.1366141
11
12
13
14
15 959
16 3146
17 Carlsbad East
18 11/01/1992
19
```

And I'm using a struct string bundle

```
/** A StringBundle contains an array of nTokens pointers to properly-
 * terminated C strings (char arrays).
 *
 * A StringBundle is said to be proper if:
 * -Tokens == NULL and nTokens == 0
 * or
 * -nTokens > 0 and Tokens points to an array of nTokens char pointers,
 * -each char pointer points to a char array of minimum size to hold
 * its string, including the terminator (no wasted space)
 */
 struct _StringBundle {
     char** Tokens; // pointer to dynamically-allocated array of char*
     uint32_t nTokens; // dimension of array pointed to by Tokens
 };
```

The field `Tokens` is a `char**` because it points to the first element in an array of `char*` variables.

I can use any of these c library functions: malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), free(), strncpy(), memcpy(), strlen(), sscanf().

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

A minimal state machine (if you want to catch the characters into new strings, you only have to repalce the fputc()s by append-to-string operations):

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int ch, pos,lin;

for (pos=lin=0;;) {
        ch = getc(stdin);
        if (ch != EOF && pos==0) printf("\n%d:" , lin);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        switch (ch) {
        default: putc(ch,stdout); break;
        case '|': lin++; pos = 0; continue;
        case '\n': putc(ch,stdout); continue;
                }
        pos++;
        }
return 0;
}
```

---

Usage:

---

```
echo '901051|Becker|Locale|NM|35|Eddy|015|322833N|1040812W|32.4759521|-104.1366141|||||959|3146|Carlsbad East|11/01/1992|' \
| ./a.out
```